# unable to pass check_estimator()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, adaboost

I was trying to write AdaBoostClassifier by myself and wanna make it scikit-learn compatible. However, my estimator can't pass `check_estimator()`. I've checked my code and the classifier works very well on my datasets.
p.s. I'm not a computer science student so I basically use simple code.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.utils.estimator_checks import check_estimator
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix,classification_report
from sklearn.utils.validation import check_X_y, check_array, check_is_fitted
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import check_classification_targets
```

```
class AdaboostClassifier(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
```

And when I run `check_estimator(AdaboostClassifier, generate_only = False)`, the error exists as below.

```
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-67c9b1a2bb34> in <module>
----> 1 check_estimator(AdaboostClassifier)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\estimator_checks.py in check_estimator(Estimator, generate_only)
    425     for estimator, check in checks_generator:
    426         try:
--> 427             check(estimator)
    428         except SkipTest as exception:
    429             # the only SkipTest thrown currently results from not

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\_testing.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    325             with warnings.catch_warnings():
    326                 warnings.simplefilter("ignore", self.category)
--> 327                 return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    328 
    329         return wrapper

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\estimator_checks.py in check_estimators_empty_data_messages(name, estimator_orig)
   1355                        "to train. Perhaps use "
   1356                        "check_array in train.".format(name)):
-> 1357         e.fit(X_zero_samples, [])
   1358 
   1359     X_zero_features = np.empty(0).reshape(3, 0)

<ipython-input-12-eb321088a172> in fit(***failed resolving arguments***)
     26         self.mis_rate = []
     27         self.index_tree = []
---> 28         data_weights = [1/len(x)]*len(x)
     29 
     30         x, y = check_X_y(x, y)

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

`x`should be input so of course, its length is zero currently.
I don't know `check_estimator()` works. Can anybody tell me?

Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

check_estimator runs a battery of tests specific for estimators (classes with fit methods), transformers (classes with transform method), and classifiers, which are identified because they inherit from the parent class ClassifierMixin.

It is difficult to explain what those tests do here, because there are quite a lot of them. The documentation on these tests is not exhaustive, so I think the only way forward is to navigate the source code, which can be found [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/utils/estimator_checks.py):

In short, to pass many of the tests run by check_estimator, the class you are developing should not raise an error during fit. In the tests, several numpy arrays are generated, that will contain the value 0. So if your class raises an error when a value is zero, like for example the division by 0, many of the tests will fail, simply because they can't be concluded, they are broken mid way.

I am not sure at the moment if there is a workaround. You can skip those tests if needed with an attribute called _more_tags() and a dictionary indicating which tests fail. For example something like this:

```
   def _more_tags(self):
        return {
            "_xfail_checks": {
                # check_estimator checks that fail:
                "check_estimators_nan_inf": "transformer allows NA",
                "check_parameters_default_constructible":
                    "transformer has 1 mandatory parameter",
                "check_transformer_preserve_dtypes":
                    "Test not relevant, transformers can change the types",
                "check_methods_sample_order_invariance":
                    "Test does not work on dataframes",
                "check_fit_idempotent": "Test does not work on dataframes",
                "check_fit1d": "Test not relevant, transformers only "
                "work with dataframes",
                "check_fit2d_predict1d":
                    "Test not relevant, transformers only "
                "work with dataframes",
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is just a suggestion, please, verify if it don`t will broke your algorithm:

```py
lenX = len(x)
if lenX == 0:
  lenX = 1
data_weights = [1/lenX]*len(x)
```

if len(x) == 0, you will set 0 to data_weights because the calcule will be (1/1)*0